# How to add Approval before Slot Swap task in Release pipeline on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

[image]

Hi!

I am using deployment slots to deploy my function app first on staging and then on production. I have the above two tasks in my release pipeline. After the function is deployed on the staging slot, I want to hold the swap task until someone (a user) verifies the deployment.

So, how can we add user approval before the slot swap task?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try to split two tasks into two stages, and then set Pre-deployment approvals for the stage where slot swap task is located.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the scenario mentioned by OP, the ask here is to have a manual intervention step before swapping staging and production slot.
Creating another stage just for swap is logically incorrect and would involve additional time in spinning up a new agent and setting context.
Deployment to staging and swap is logically a single job with multiple tasks (steps). To use stage in this scenario is not the best practice.

Answer (score 2):

There is a task called "Manual Intervention" You can use that to pause pipeline and resume it when validation is complete.

So the steps would be:

1. deploy to staging
2. manual intervention -> validate and click on Resume button
3. swap slots

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=azure-devops

Comment: I am trying to follow your approach, it does indeed make sense. The problem is that the Manual Intervention Job is agentless and how does not know when to wait for Intervention. If the Deplot and Swap task are on the same agent, how would you pause between the two tasks? Where do you define the sequence of the tasks and put the agentless job in between? I am using classic releases in devops.